# Can't seem to adapt window.focus and window.onblur to my situation

Tags: javascript

So what i want to do is this: if my ajax request returns something, i want to play a sound. If within 15s the user gets to the tab, then nothing ever happens. But if it takes him more than 15s, then an alarm is fired. I can't seem to get this behavior to work....

```
 $.getJSON('/orders/'+restaurant+'/.json', function(data) { 

 $.each(data, function(key, val) {
     //does some processing on the data
 });
 if (data.length > 0){
  $('#play_sound').html('<iframe width="1" height="1" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3puTnBV8DbQ?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" ></iframe>');


  setTimeout
  (
    function()
     {
       var isActive;

       window.focus = function (){
         isActive = true;
       }
       window.onblur = function() {
         isActive = false;
       };

       if ((!isActive)){
         alert('ajax request returned info');
        }
      }
  , 15000
); 
}
```

Now i kind of know that i maybe need an extra variable which is like a counter...i don't know..

Suggestions ?

Comment: where's the ajax part?

Comment: @koala_dev i didn't put it because it will be too long..anyway..the ajax part is correct and it works

Comment: @AndréDion isn't setTimeout beeing called only once ?

Comment: Please include all relevant code when asking for help with debugging. Your Ajax and audio playback code are relevant.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `window.onfocus`?

Comment: @AndréDion this is all the relevant code from my point of view..but fine..i will add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current process looks like this:

1. An ajax request succeeds.
2. 15 seconds later, `setTimeout` creates two event handlers to listen for `window.focus` (which should be **`window.onfocus`**) and `window.onblur`.
3. In the same `setTimeout` call, the value of `isActive` is checked, and it's `undefined`. Since the script hasn't had time to listen for the focus or blur events -- as they were created earlier in the same `setTimeout` statement -- that means `isActive` hasn't been given a value.

Your variable `isActive`, as well as the function, should be declared separately and globally:

```
var isActive = true;
window.onfocus = function () {
    isActive = true;
};
window.onblur = function() {
    isActive = false;
};
```

Then, use your timeout like so:

```
// Ajax request succeeds above

setTimeout(function() {
    if (!isActive) {
        alert("ajax request returned info");
    }
}, 15000);
```

This way, `isActive` is a globally available variable that will always know whether or not the window is active.

### Edit

There's another issue. What if the user hears the notification, focuses on the window to read it, and then blurs the window again? When 15 seconds pass, even if the notification has already been seen, the alert will still be given since the window's not in focus.

So, let's fix this by setting your `setTimeout` to a reminder variable, **which we can cancel once the window is focused.**

```
var isActive = true;
var reminder = false;
window.onfocus = function () {
    isActive = true;
    if (reminder !== false) {
        clearTimeout(reminder);
        reminder = false;
    }
};
window.onblur = function() {
    isActive = false;
};
```

Then, replace the second snippet with this:

```
// Ajax request succeeds above

reminder = setTimeout(function() {
    if (!isActive) {
        alert("ajax request returned info");
    }
}, 15000);
```

So, if the user sees the notification before the alert goes off, then the alert will be canceled.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code.

First one would be that you are overwriting the window object's `focus` method instead of assigning a handler via `onfocus`.

Second issue is that you need to assign the handlers outside of your timeout and the success callback so that the data will be available when the timeout is executed:

```
dvar isActive = true; //the window is focused when the code is executed first

//all this will happen independently of the AJAX call so that state is available when the timeout executes

window.onfocus = function () {
     isActive = true; //window gains focus while waiting for the AJAX call to finish
};
window.onblur = function () {
       isActive = false; //window loses focus focus while waiting for the AJAX call to finish  
};

$.getJSON('/orders/' + restaurant + '/.json', function (data) {

    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        //does some processing on the data
    });
    if (data.length > 0) {
        $('#play_sound').html('<iframe width="1" height="1" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/3puTnBV8DbQ?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" ></iframe>');

        setTimeout(function () {
            if ((!isActive)) {
                alert('ajax request returned info');
            }
        }, 15000);
    }
});
```